# Retuning complex tree like structures in NEO4J without duplication

Tags: node.js, database, neo4j, cypher

I have a method `getPhotosInBucket` which is to return all photos where a `[:IN]` relationship exists in a given bucket where each photo has its own set of relationships to `Meta` nodes that each contain properties corresponding to a different version of the image eg. small, medium, thumbnail etc. To make things even more complicated, each photo also has a creator and each creator has a thumbnail which like a photo has multiple `Meta` nodes related to it.

Below is a cut down version of what would be returned. In this example there is only one user who created the bucket and created each photo but in the real world user James could have a bucket containing 100 different images each with their own creator, thumbnail and creator thumbnail.

The query used to return this data is a little verbose and was just to demonstrate my structure a little bit and generate a visual graph:

```
    MATCH (album:Asset:Album:Bucket {name: 'Bucketjamesprivate'})
    MATCH (album)<-[:CREATED]-(creator)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (album)<-[:THUMBNAIL]-(albumThumb)<-[:META]-(albumThumbMeta)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (creator)<-[:THUMBNAIL]-(creatorThumb)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (creatorThumb)<-[:META]-(creatorThumbMeta)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (album)<-[:IN]-(photos)<-[:META]-(meta)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (photos)<-[:CREATED]-(photoOwner)<-[:THUMBNAIL]-(photoThumbnail)<-[:META]-(photoThumbnailMeta)
    RETURN DISTINCT album, albumThumb, albumThumbMeta, creator, creatorThumb, photos, meta, photoOwner, photoThumbnailMeta
```

This ends up returning the following:

[image]

As you can see, James created 1 bucket, 1 bucket thumbnail with 3 meta nodes, 2 photos IN the bucket each with 3 meta nodes and finally he has a thumbnail with 3 meta nodes.

The actual number of rows returned is 54 which can only grow exponentially when I have even just a handful of photos in a bucket to return so perhaps there is a more performant way of doing this.

I have tried using the collect method but it introduces some strange duplication which I'm sure is expected but I don't understand it well enough to know why.

The object I would like my method to return in the end would be something like this:

```
    {
        album: {
            name: 'etc',
            foo: 'bar',
            bar: 'foo'
        },
        albumThumb: [
            {
                type: 'small',
                src: 'www.foo.com/small'
            },
            {
                type: 'medium',
                src: 'www.foo.com/medium'
            }
        ],
        creator: {
            name: 'James',
            foo: 'bar'
        },
        creatorThumb: [
            {
                type: 'small',
                src: 'www.foo.com/small'
            },
            {
                type: 'medium',
                src: 'www.foo.com/medium'
            }
        ],
        photos: [
            {
                photo: {
                    name: 'Photo 1',
                    date: '112432543636'
                },
                meta: [
                    {
                        type: 'small',
                        src: 'www.foo.com/small'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'medium',
                        src: 'www.foo.com/medium'
                    }
                ],
                creator: {
                    name: 'James',
                    foo: 'bar'
                },
                creatorThumb: [
                    {
                        type: 'small',
                        src: 'www.foo.com/small'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'medium',
                        src: 'www.foo.com/medium'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                photo: {
                    name: 'Photo 2',
                    date: '112432543636'
                },
                meta: [
                    {
                        type: 'small',
                        src: 'www.foo.com/small'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'medium',
                        src: 'www.foo.com/medium'
                    }
                ],
                creator: {
                    name: 'James',
                    foo: 'bar'
                },
                creatorThumb: [
                    {
                        type: 'small',
                        src: 'www.foo.com/small'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'medium',
                        src: 'www.foo.com/medium'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Be it a photo in a bucket or a photo that is a thumbnail of some other node, there will only be a handful of meta nodes for each photo.

I'd also like to allow the client on the front end to paginate the photos, is there a way I can `LIMIT` and `SKIP` the photos `IN` the bucket?

Should I approach this differently and make 2 separate transactions? One to get the album, albumThumb, creator, creatorThumb and another to get the photos and associated thumbs?

Comment: I don't have time to write out a longer answer now, but you should look into the `WITH` clause if you haven't already.  You could do a few matches, pass on some values and do some `collect()`ing in that `WITH` and then do some more matching, rinse and repeat.

Comment: Hi @BrianUnderwood thanks for the comment. I have tried using `WITH` and `collect()` but i get strange duplication thats just as bad as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a bit more time now, let me give it a shot ;)

```
MATCH (album:Asset:Album:Bucket {name: 'Bucketjamesprivate'})
MATCH (album)<-[:CREATED]-(creator)
OPTIONAL MATCH (album)<-[:THUMBNAIL]-(albumThumb)<-[:META]-(albumThumbMeta)

WITH
  album,
  collect({src: albumThumb.src, type: albumThumbMeta.type}) AS albumThumbs,
  creator

OPTIONAL MATCH (creator)<-[:THUMBNAIL]-(creatorThumb)<-[:META]-(creatorThumbMeta)

WITH
  album,
  albumThumbs,
  creator,
  collect({src: creatorThumb.src, type: creatorThumbMeta.type}) AS creatorThumbs

OPTIONAL MATCH (album)<-[:IN]-(photo)<-[:META]-(photoMeta)
OPTIONAL MATCH
  (photo)<-[:CREATED]-(photoOwner)<-[:THUMBNAIL]-(ownerThumb)
  <-[:META]-(ownerThumbMeta)

WITH
  album,
  albumThumbs,
  creator,
  creatorThumbs,
  photo,
  collect({src: photo.src, type: photoMeta.type}) AS photoMeta,
  photoOwner,
  collect({src: ownerThumb.src, type: ownerThumbMeta.type}) AS ownerThumbs

RETURN
  album,
  albumThumbs,
  creator,
  creatorThumbs,
  collect({
    photo: photo,
    meta: photoMeta,
    owner: photoOwner,
    ownerThumbs: ownerThumbs}) AS photos
```

Hopefully that will do it for you, or at least get you close enough!

This is my `CREATE` statement, BTW, in case anybody want to give it a shot:

```
CREATE
  (bucket:Bucket {name: 'Bucketjamesprivate'})<-[:CREATED]-(james:Person {name: 'James'}),
  (p1:Photo)-[:IN]->(bucket),
  (p1)<-[:CREATED]-(james),
  (p1)<-[:META]-(:Meta {type: 'small'}),
  (p1)<-[:META]-(:Meta {type: 'medium'}),
  (p1)<-[:META]-(:Meta {type: 'small_sq'}),
  (p2:Photo)-[:IN]->(bucket),
  (p2)<-[:CREATED]-(james),
  (p2)<-[:META]-(:Meta {type: 'small'}),
  (p2)<-[:META]-(:Meta {type: 'medium'}),
  (p2)<-[:META]-(:Meta {type: 'small_sq'}),
  (bucket_thumb:Thumbnail)-[:THUMBNAIL]->(bucket),
  (bucket_thumb)<-[:CREATED]-(james),
  (bucket_thumb)<-[:META]-(:Meta {type: 'small'}),
  (bucket_thumb)<-[:META]-(:Meta {type: 'medium'}),
  (bucket_thumb)<-[:META]-(:Meta {type: 'small_sq'}),
  (james_thumb:Thumbnail)-[:THUMBNAIL]->(james),
  (james_thumb)<-[:CREATED]-(james),
  (james_thumb)<-[:META]-(:Meta {type: 'small'}),
  (james_thumb)<-[:META]-(:Meta {type: 'medium'}),
  (james_thumb)<-[:META]-(:Meta {type: 'small_sq'})
```

Comment: I came up with something pretty similar to that but your solution is much more concise than mine. Thank you.